# Enter multiple strings on one line with a sentinel value into an array (java)

Tags: java, loops, input

I'm trying to enter multiple strings into an array but they all have to be on the same line and stop when the sentinel value is entered. This is what I have so far.

```
        String [] courses = new String [5];
        for (int k = 0; !(input.next().equals("xxx")); k++) {
            courses[k] = input.next();
        }
```

It seems like the for loop isn't looping, when I check the array after it will only have the last string before "xxx", and none of the previously entered ones. All of the input must be on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption that you are using the java.util.Scanner class to get console input and you have an fixed array.

There are two main problems with the code above:
When using the method next() it will read one line and this line will be gone.
What will happen if you have 10 tokens and not 5?

```
String[] courses = new String[5];
for(int i = 0; input.hasNext(); i++) {
    String token = input.next();
    if ("xxx".equals(token)) {
        break;
    }
    courses[i] = token;
}
```

Comment: I can't use lists for this project unfortunately. It is assumed that there will never be more than five inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using **while** loop is better in your case

```
String [] courses = new String[5];

int k = 0;

while(!(input.next().equals("xxx")) && k < 5) {
  courses[k] = input.next();
  k++;
}
```